# Make Transparent Window Not Clickthrough

Tags: c++, winapi

So I'm using CEF3 on Window x64, latest build, and I needed to create a POC for work where I loading a specific web page through CEF and the window had to be semi transparent.  I managed to do that, but now, when you click on the page it loaded, the clicks seem to click through the window, so you can't actually navigate the page.

Does anyone know how to have both a semi transparent window AND have the clicks not go through?

Here's the code I used for the transparency.  I've Googled the shit out of this, but can't seem to find a solution to my problem.  Additionally, I'm really bad with the Win32 API, otherwise I bet this would have been much easier!

Thank you so much in advance!

```
BOOL MakeWindowTransparent(HWND hWnd, unsigned char factor) {
/* First, see if we can get the API call we need. If we've tried
* once, we don't need to try again. */
if (!initialized) {
  HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"user32");

  pSetLayeredWindowAttributes =
    (PSLWA) GetProcAddress(hDLL, "SetLayeredWindowAttributes");

  initialized = TRUE;
}

if (pSetLayeredWindowAttributes == NULL)
  return FALSE;

/* Windows need to be layered to be made transparent. This is done
* by modifying the extended style bits to contain WS_EX_LAYARED. */
SetLastError(0);

SetWindowLong(hWnd,
  GWL_EXSTYLE,
  GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);

if (GetLastError())
  return FALSE;

/* Now, we need to set the 'layered window attributes'. This
* is where the alpha values get set. */
return pSetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,
  RGB(255, 255, 255),
  factor,
  LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA);
```

}

Comment: If you set the alpha to `1` instead of `0` it will still look transparent but clicks will be registered.

Comment: Windows implement the rockhard rule that a window that is transparent to the user's eye is transparent to the mouse as well.  Technically you can take advantage of a bug in Aero.  *Some* colorkey values are not transparent to the mouse.  Pretty random, RGB(255, 0, 0) will do it.  The bug has been around a long time, very unlikely they can still fix it.

Comment: Hans Passant, this partially did what I needed it to.  Are there other values that have this bug and are they documented anywhere?

Comment: There are others, their values are random.  Pretty hard to ever get anybody to document a bug :)

Comment: What does `pSetLayeredWindowAttributes` look like?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce @HansPassant's workaround on Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

Removing `LWA_COLORKEY` works (at least) in AHK.
Refer to the [source](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey/blob/master/Source/script2.cpp) and search for:

```
MySetLayeredWindowAttributes(target_window, 0, value, LWA_ALPHA);
```